# How to fetch room list from openfire?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

I am using openfire server and XMPP protocol for chatting and i got success in it.

Now i want to implement room chatting. I google lots about it, what i get is 'Joing Room', 'Create Room' but first i want to get list of all room name from conferrance.

i have conferance and room in it  :

```
#define CONFERENCE_ROOM_SERVER      @"chatroomforfriends"
#define CONFERENCE_ROOM_NAME        @"cr1"
```

'chatroomforfriends' is conferance name and it contain 'cr1' room.

How do i fetch all room name in iOS ?

Answer (score 1):

As per MUC XEP (0045) you can get list of all rooms by querying:

```
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
id='zb8q41f4'
to='chat.shakespeare.lit'
type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>
```

and you get the response as:

```
<iq from='chat.shakespeare.lit'
  id='zb8q41f4' to='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda' type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'>
    <item jid='heath@chat.shakespeare.lit'
      name='A Lonely Heath'/>
    <item jid='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
      name='A Dark Cave'/>
    <item jid='forres@chat.shakespeare.lit'
      name='The Palace'/>
    <item jid='inverness@chat.shakespeare.lit'
      name='Macbeth&apos;s Castle'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Details are mentioned in [XEP-0045](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-rooms)

This method returns all public rooms hosted by MUC Service.
To get private rooms, or to get rooms of a specific user, you will have to write a plugin to handle your custom query (XMPP Way) or you can write a servlet (HTTP Way) in Openfire for this.

Comment: yea, i got all room, but as you say it fetch all room, but i need to fetch only room associated with user.

Comment: Then easiest way is to make an HTTP Service (either in Openfire Project or Standalone with access to Openfire DB). The service will take user jid as request param and it can query openfire db for picking all rooms of the user and also the affiliation (owner, admin) of the user and the list can be parsed by application.