# How to fetch room list of particular user xmpp?

Tags: ios, objective-c, openfire, xmp

I'm fetching user room list and it fetch all created rooms. But i want only room list that user have.

Here is the code that im using :

```
-(void) getListofRooms
{
    NSString* server = @"conference.test";
    XMPPJID *servrJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:server];
    XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" to:servrJID];

    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[xmppStream myJID].full];

    NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query"];
    [query addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];
    [iq addChild:query];

    [xmppStream sendElement:iq];
}
```

Here is my XML responce :

```
RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" from="conference.test" to="user@test/2ufrroh7xi">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">
    <item jid="ios@conference.test" name="ios"/>
    <item jid="newroom@conference.test" name="newRoomNatureName"/>
    <item jid="jay@conference.test" name="jay"/>
    <item jid="crs@conference.test" name="aaa"/>
    <item jid="newRoom@conference.test" name="newRoomNatureName"/>
    </query>
    </iq>
```

Comment: just print your xml or json response value here

Comment: plz check xml responce

Comment: what you want to revel the data from the response

Comment: it displays all records that in the database even if i'm not a member of it. I want only room that im associate with it.

Comment: how can find you are not a member

Comment: im not in, i created this grp and from database.

Comment: Problem being discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656544/how-to-fetch-room-list-from-openfire/38685904?noredirect=1#comment64802614_38685904